# Where to ask questions related laptop and computer drivers

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have few questions regarding:

1. Computer hardware drivers
2. Laptop specifications
3. Computer hardware specifications

I just want to know where can I ask these questions.

Comment: What questions in particular do you have? Offsite resource questions are off-topic on most sites so there may not be a site for your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: @gnat: Dupe is completely wrong, since it's about software and programming instead of hardware and drivers.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

In its [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) page, it specifically states that you can ask questions about:

> Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking

Please make sure that your questions are specific and follows other rules as seen the site's Help Center to avoid a hailstorm of downvotes and closures.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what your issue is.

I'll handle 2 and 3 first.

These are *broad* recommendations - I encourage you to spend a little while looking at the sites and rules to get a feel of what's on topic there.

If you want to know "what hardware fits your needs" the [hardware recommendations beta](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be a good start. As with the other recommendations sites try to make it very clear what fits your needs - [start here](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality)

If you want to know what something *is* [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) might be a good start, but I'd pop into SU's main chat room [root access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access), ask first, and if folk there direct you to the main site ask there.

Drivers are a bit of a sore point for me personally. They *partially* have the same issue as most software recommendations - they do possibly go obsolete, new versions ought to be trivial to find, and SU should be a *last* resort after trying to get things to work. If a driver is *acting up* SU's a good place. If you need to *find* a driver, manufacturer's website should be the first port of call.

*How* to get a driver to work may be fine. *What driver to use* depends on the question, but make sure you make it clear you've done your due diligence.